# Probability of having a disease given that 20 people have it out of 100 random people

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

> Each person has a disease with probability $p$ independently. Out of $100$ random persons, $20$ tested positive. what is the value of $p$? Assume that the disease can be tested accurately with no false positives.

A first glance suggests that $P(B(100,p)=20)=1$. But turns out this never holds for any $p\in[0,1]$. Also, another perspective leads to believing that since we were able to find $20$ infected people from a "random" set of $100$ people, what we have at hand is a uniform distribution, so $p=20/100$. Could anybody clarify?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, there is no such thing as "the value of $p$" given this information. Any $p \in (0, 1)$ could theoretically produce this outcome. What you can compute is the maximum likelihood value of $p$, namely the value of $p$ that maximizes the probability (density) of this outcome (which turns out to be the intuitive $p = \frac{20}{100}$, but this requires a nontrivial calculation).

Comment: Given the data the best estimate (in a sense that can be made explicit) is $p = 0.2$. That's about all you can say.

Comment: @EthanBolker: *a* best estimate.  There are other criteria that can lead to other answers

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there some hint of using a Negative Binomial random variable somehow given this scenario?